# Jenkins Groovy unix Script Error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean mightBePositionalArgumentConstructor VariableExpression

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to to create Jenkins pipeline and have the below line which I copied from existing working pipeline in the same Jenkins instance.

```
script {
                def GitDValue = sh (
                    script: "pwd",
                    returnStdout: true
                 ).trim()
                echo "GitDirectory: ${GitDValue}"
            }
```

I replaced actual shell script command with `pwd` in this question for simplicity. Even `pwd` fails. I also followed below article to set up my pipeline
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-create-an-automatic-ecs-deployment-with-jenkins-84c0e83e7cd0

Interestingly above code doesn't fail in my local jenkins instance. It only fails in server.

Exception stacktrace is below.

Any help is appreciated.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.SandboxTransformer.mightBePositionalArgumentConstructor(org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.VariableExpression)'
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.SandboxCpsTransformer.visitAssignmentOrCast(SandboxCpsTransformer.java:93)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer$42.run(CpsTransformer.java:1171)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeChildren(CpsTransformer.java:446)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeNode(CpsTransformer.java:409)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visitDeclarationExpression(CpsTransformer.java:1164)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.DeclarationExpression.visit(DeclarationExpression.java:89)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.java:357)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visitExpressionStatement(CpsTransformer.java:589)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:42)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.java:357)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.java:363)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer$5.run(CpsTransformer.java:515)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeChildren(CpsTransformer.java:446)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeNode(CpsTransformer.java:409)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visitBlockStatement(CpsTransformer.java:512)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:71)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.java:357)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer$2.run(CpsTransformer.java:388)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeChildren(CpsTransformer.java:446)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeNode(CpsTransformer.java:409)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visitWithSafepoint(CpsTransformer.java:374)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer$27.run(CpsTransformer.java:932)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeChildren(CpsTransformer.java:446)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeNode(CpsTransformer.java:409)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visitClosureExpression(CpsTransformer.java:898)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ClosureExpression.visit(ClosureExpression.java:49)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.java:357)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.java:363)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer$4.run(CpsTransformer.java:505)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeChildren(CpsTransformer.java:446)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeNode(CpsTransformer.java:409)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visitMethodCallExpression(CpsTransformer.java:487)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MethodCallExpression.visit(MethodCallExpression.java:70)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.java:357)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visitExpressionStatement(CpsTransformer.java:589)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:42)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.java:357)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.java:363)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer$5.run(CpsTransformer.java:515)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeChildren(CpsTransformer.java:446)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeNode(CpsTransformer.java:409)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visitBlockStatement(CpsTransformer.java:512)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:71)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.java:357)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer$2.run(CpsTransformer.java:388)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeChildren(CpsTransformer.java:446)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeNode(CpsTransformer.java:409)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visitWithSafepoint(CpsTransformer.java:374)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer$27.run(CpsTransformer.java:932)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeChildren(CpsTransformer.java:446)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeNode(CpsTransformer.java:409)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visitClosureExpression(CpsTransformer.java:898)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ClosureExpression.visit(ClosureExpression.java:49)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.java:357)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.java:363)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer$18.run(CpsTransformer.java:702)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeChildren(CpsTransformer.java:446)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeNode(CpsTransformer.java:409)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visitStaticMethodCallExpression(CpsTransformer.java:696)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.StaticMethodCallExpression.visit(StaticMethodCallExpression.java:45)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.java:357)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.java:363)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer$19.run(CpsTransformer.java:714)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeChildren(CpsTransformer.java:446)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeNode(CpsTransformer.java:409)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visitConstructorCallExpression(CpsTransformer.java:709)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ConstructorCallExpression.visit(ConstructorCallExpression.java:46)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.java:357)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.java:363)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer$29.run(CpsTransformer.java:976)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeChildren(CpsTransformer.java:446)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeNode(CpsTransformer.java:409)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visitListExpression(CpsTransformer.java:973)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ListExpression.visit(ListExpression.java:64)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.java:357)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.java:363)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer$19.run(CpsTransformer.java:714)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeChildren(CpsTransformer.java:446)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeNode(CpsTransformer.java:409)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visitConstructorCallExpression(CpsTransformer.java:709)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ConstructorCallExpression.visit(ConstructorCallExpression.java:46)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.java:357)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.java:363)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer$19.run(CpsTransformer.java:714)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeChildren(CpsTransformer.java:446)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeNode(CpsTransformer.java:409)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visitConstructorCallExpression(CpsTransformer.java:709)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ConstructorCallExpression.visit(ConstructorCallExpression.java:46)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.java:357)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer$11.run(CpsTransformer.java:597)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeChildren(CpsTransformer.java:446)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeNode(CpsTransformer.java:409)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visitReturnStatement(CpsTransformer.java:594)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ReturnStatement.visit(ReturnStatement.java:49)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.java:357)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.java:363)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer$5.run(CpsTransformer.java:515)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeChildren(CpsTransformer.java:446)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeNode(CpsTransformer.java:409)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visitBlockStatement(CpsTransformer.java:512)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:71)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.java:357)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer$2.run(CpsTransformer.java:388)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeChildren(CpsTransformer.java:446)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeNode(CpsTransformer.java:409)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visitWithSafepoint(CpsTransformer.java:374)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer$27.run(CpsTransformer.java:932)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeChildren(CpsTransformer.java:446)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeNode(CpsTransformer.java:409)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visitClosureExpression(CpsTransformer.java:898)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ClosureExpression.visit(ClosureExpression.java:49)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.java:357)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.java:363)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer$4.run(CpsTransformer.java:505)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeChildren(CpsTransformer.java:446)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeNode(CpsTransformer.java:409)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visitMethodCallExpression(CpsTransformer.java:487)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MethodCallExpression.visit(MethodCallExpression.java:70)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.java:357)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visitExpressionStatement(CpsTransformer.java:589)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:42)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.java:357)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.java:363)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer$5.run(CpsTransformer.java:515)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeChildren(CpsTransformer.java:446)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeNode(CpsTransformer.java:409)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visitBlockStatement(CpsTransformer.java:512)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:71)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.java:357)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer$2.run(CpsTransformer.java:388)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeChildren(CpsTransformer.java:446)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeNode(CpsTransformer.java:409)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visitWithSafepoint(CpsTransformer.java:374)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visitMethod(CpsTransformer.java:231)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.SandboxCpsTransformer.visitMethod(SandboxCpsTransformer.java:73)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.call(CpsTransformer.java:136)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.SandboxCpsTransformer.call(SandboxCpsTransformer.java:29)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1087)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:624)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:602)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:579)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:323)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:293)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:677)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:689)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:561)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:513)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:335)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
```

Finished: FAILURE

[UPDATE]
I found a work around for this. Instead of `sh (script, returnStdout)`, I am sending output to file and reading from file. Thanks to another stackoverflow answer.

Now, when I assign that to `int` , it fails again.
If I don't specify datatype, it works fine.

something to do datatypes `int, true`

Comment: For the record, this bug is tracked at: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-69978

Comment: Yes , it worked after the update.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It worked after updating groovy pipeline plugin.

There are two Jenkins plugins that offer groovy script functionality: "Pipeline: Groovy" and "Pipeline: Groovy Libraries".
The first one caters to groovy scripts, the second one offers the possibility to import and use groovy scripts saved as libraries on Jenkins.
Both of them have to match the Jenkins version onto which they run.

Comment: Thanks it works after upgrading "groovy: Pipeline" plugin.